# expected primary-expression before ']' token"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
//Purpose: To simulate the probability that a car will make a decision in a video game.
//40% of the time the car will turn left, 30% right, 20% straight, and 10% explode.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void GetCount( count[] );

int main()
{
  int count[4] = {0};
  unsigned int k;
  float theoretical;

  srand( (unsigned) time(NULL) );

  GetCount( int count[] );

  cout.setf( ios::showpoint | ios::fixed );
  cout << setprecision(2);
  cout << "                                 Car Simulation" << endl << endl
       << "                Number of        Experimental        Theoretical    % Error  " << endl
       << "             Times Selected        Percent             Percent               " << endl
       << "            ----------------    --------------      -------------    ------  " << endl;

  for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++ )
  {
      switch(k)
      {
          case 0:
              cout << "Left:     ";
              theoretical = 40;
              break;
          case 1:
              cout << "Right:    ";
              theoretical = 30;
              break;
          case 2:
              cout << "Straight: ";
              theoretical = 20;
              break;
          default:
              cout << "Explosion:";
              theoretical = 10;
              break;
      } // end switch 

           cout << setw( 12 ) << count[ k ] 
                << setw( 20 ) << count[ k ] / 10000.0 * 100.0
                << setw( 19 ) << theoretical 
                << setw( 13 ) << ( ( count[ k ] - theoretical * 100 ) / (theoretical * 100) * 100 )
              << endl << endl;
  } //end for 

cout << endl << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;

} //end main

void GetCount( int count[] )
{
    int randNum;
    unsigned int k;

   for( k = 0; k < 10000; k++ )//generates random number 1-100 10,000 times
   {
      randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

      if( randNum <= 100 && randNum > 60 )
           count[0]++; 
      else if( randNum <= 60 && randNum > 30 )
           count[1]++; 
      else if( randNum <= 30 && randNum > 10 )
           count[2]++; 
      else 
           count[3]++; 
  }//end for

}//end function definition
```

The code above is made to simulate a car making decisions in a video game.

At an intersection, 40 % of the time the car will turn left, 30% right, 20% straight, and 10% of the time the car will explode.

The program executes 10,000 of these decisions and outputs the results.

Everything works great except for the function "GetCount()". This function, when called, is supposed to generate random numbers representing the decisions and store the amount of times each numbers were generated in their array.

However, when I compile the program, I get an error saying:

```
"in line 21, expected primary-expression before ']' token".
```

This is the same line where I call the function. I have tried a few things to try and fix it but I keep getting some error.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetCount( int count[] );
```

Should be

```
GetCount(count);
```

The type doesn't have to be repeated; the compiler knows that `count` is the same variable you just declared as an `int[]`.